# How to return values only for the first row in a group

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have the below sample data

```
MasterRecordId, MasterRecordDate, TargetDate, MasterRecordIdCount
1              | 15/02/2017      |02/02/2017  | 3
1              | 15/02/2017      |05/08/2017  | 3
1              | 15/02/2017      |12/12/2017  | 3
2              | 12/05/2017      |07/08/2017  | 2
2              | 12/05/2017      |10/08/2017  | 2
```

When i do a select query i want the output to be like below

```
MasterRecordId, MasterRecordDate, TargetDate, MasterRecordIdCount
1              | 15/02/2017      |02/02/2017  | 3
1              |                 |05/08/2017  | 
1              |                 |12/12/2017  | 
2              |                 |07/08/2017  | 2
2              | 12/05/2017      |10/08/2017  |
```

Basically, `MasterRecordDate` and `MasterRecordIdCount` for `MasterRecordId`1  will always be the same so i dont want to repeat.

Comment: " 12/05/2017   " for the MasterRecordId = 2 should be with the first record

Comment: are you sure you want to do this? it will return columns with empty values anyway

Comment: This can be done with `LAG`, but as others have said: Don't do this in SQL; do this in your app or Webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the type of transformation that you should be doing in the application layer.  Why?  Because the result set from your version depends entirely on the ordering of the results.

You *can* do this in SQL, but you need to ensure the final ordering:

```
select MasterRecordId,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then MasterRecordDate end) as MasterRecordDate,
       TargetDate,
       (case when seqnum = 1 then MasterRecordIdCount end) as MasterRecordIdCount
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by MasterRecordId order by TargetDate) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
order by MasterRecordId, TargetDate;
```

Two very important points.

(1) The outer query needs an `order by` to ensure that the result set is ordered appropriately.  SQL does not guarantee the ordering of a result set unless you explicitly specify an `order by`.

(2) You might be tempted to eliminate the subquery and use `row_number()` twice.  That does work for the data you have provided.  However, if two dates are the same, you would run the risk of the two `row_numbers()` returning "1" on different rows.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT MasterRecordId,
       ISNULL((CASE WHEN RN = 1 then MasterRecordDate END),'') AS MasterRecordDate,
       TargetDate,
       ISNULL((CASE WHEN RN = 1 then MasterRecordIdCount END),'') AS MasterRecordIdCount
FROM(
    SELECT MasterRecordId, MasterRecordDate, TargetDate, MasterRecordIdCount
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MasterRecordId ORDER BY TargetDate)RN
    FROM Your_Table
    )D
ORDER BY MasterRecordId, TargetDate
```